# Set every Integer in Arraylist to certain value

Tags: java, arraylist

I try to do it like this, but somehow it doesn't seem to work:

`ArrayList<Integer> possible_values= new ArrayList<Integer>();`

```
public void setValueToZero(){
   for (Integer temp : possible_values) {
      temp=0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Try a simpler (but equivalent) piece of code: `Integer a = 3; Integer b = a; b = 0; System.out.println(a);`.  What happens?

Comment: You're assigning 0 value to temp, not to element of "possible_values". Becouse temp is a new object in the heap. This for loop is different from the iteration logic. You must use that for loop: Integer temp; Integer i; for(i=0; i<possible_values.size(); i++) possible_values.get(i) = 0;

Comment: first off all: great first post. short, indicating what you want and you showed what you have already tried. there is already a good answer how to do what you want to do, but as to why your code doesnt work: temp is only a temporary local variable. its not a pointer which you share with your list. if you change the local variable the list doesnt know anything about it. you explicitly need to tell the list!

Comment: @kodmanyagha - That won't work either (it won't even compile).

Comment: Thanks for the input. Now I get why it doesn't work.

Comment: i made a small change to the code from @kodmanyagha.
this way it will do what you wanted (although there is a much nicer answer by "Jahnold"). just for your understanding:
for(i=0; i<possible_values.size(); i++){ possible_values.set(i, 0);}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Collections.fill(List<T> list, T obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#fill-java.util.List-T-).

In your case that would be `Collections.fill(possible_values, 0)`

Answer (score -1):

You are assigning values to `temp` variable and there is no change to the `possible_values` list object elements, you can `set` the `0` values to the `List` elements as shown below:

```
public void setValueToZero(ArrayList<Integer> possible_values){
    for (int i=0; i<possible_values.size(); i++) {
       possible_values.set(i, 0);
    }
}
```

or else, you can use streams (one liner code) as shown below:

```
IntStream.range(0,possible_values.size()).forEach(i->possible_values.set(i, 0));
```

Comment: capitalisation, code block and bolt all mixed up so tightly? that hurts to look at ;(

Comment: It would be really good if someone explains what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Unboxing has nothing to do with the problem, and there isn't even any unboxing here. On the contrary: 0 is boxed to Integer, and then assigned to temp.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for responding, In the OP's code, `temp` is `Integer` type so I specified it as unboxing

Comment: Yes, and it's wrong (and irrelevant). A value of type Integer needs to be assigned to temp, since it's of type Integer. O is not of type Integer. It's of type int. So it's boxed to Integer. If there was not boxing/autoboxing, you would have to write `temp = Integer.valueOf(0)`. That's boxing, i.e. wrapping a primitive into an object. Unboxing is `int i = smeInteger.intValue()`, i.e. accessing the primitive wrapped into the Integer. But, again, it's totally irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score -2):

The  **temp** in your program **is not** the elements of the ArrayList,it is a new Object. In the other word, your program is not to set the integer in arraylist. You are just set the value of **temp**,which is a new object and you didn't change the **true value** of the element in the arraylist.  Well, I hope you can understand what I write. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: hello and welcome to stackoverflow. thanks for taking the time to answer. you are not quite correct though. it is the same object! you can test it with putting an item into the list, iterating over it and checking with ==, which will be true.. the problem is that you are creating a "pointer" to that object and then you change the "pointer" to another object. also: you didn't actually provide a solution, which your answer should optimally include one.